# Point local TNS listener to remote database

Tags: oracle, nextep

I'm using neXtep to compare databases, and I'd like to use it for version control for an Oracle database. The connect string

REPORT_DEV2 = (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbs-nprd1-vm-002.mycompany.com)(PORT=1550))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DEV.MYCOMPANY.COM)))

works with tnsping

```
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 02-DEC-2019 21:22:55

Copyright (c) 1997, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\woodsman\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbs-nprd1-vm-002.mycompany.com)(PORT=1550))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DEV.MYCOMPANY.COM)))
OK (20 msec)
```

The dialog 
[image: Connection dialog]
Is misleading. When I give it the service name as the database name, it says:

ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of a SID in the given connect descriptor.

I have *no* way of telling it to use a service name and not a SID.  I'm hoping I can set up a TNS Listener entry in my local tnsnames.ora file that points to the service name that I want to use.  Oh, and the neXtep program is on github, but is no longer being supported.  Worse, I've tried but cannot figure out how to build it myself so that I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a SID to use. It seems that while I normally use a service name, somehow there's a local SID that gets built as part of the Oracle installation process. Nonetheless, for anyone who uses nexTep for Oracle, please make sure you have access to the SID name.

The Database name prompt in the nexTep dialog is really asking for a SID name. Bonus points to anyone willing to fix this one issue with nexTep so people can, out of the box, use an Oracle service name. Even better if they can change it to allow a straight up JDBC URL like every other Java based program.